# Rails SQL Query counts

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table called "Books" that has_many "Chapters" and I would like to get all Books that have have more than 10 chapters. How do I do this in a single query?

I have this so far...

```
Books.joins('LEFT JOIN chapters ON chapters.book_id = books.id')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution...

```
query = <<-SQL
  UPDATE books AS b
  INNER JOIN
  (
      SELECT books.id
      FROM books
      JOIN chapters ON chapters.book_id = books.id
      GROUP BY books.id
      HAVING count(chapters.id) > 10
  ) i
  ON b.id = i.id
  SET long_book = true;
SQL

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query using Rails 4, ActiveRecord

```
Book.includes(:chapters).references(:chapters).group('books.id').having('count(chapters.id) > 10')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the rails very well but the SQL would be like this:

```
SELECT b.* FROM Books b 
JOIN Chapters c ON b.id = c.book_id 
GROUP BY b.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
```

According to the ActiveRecord docs it would then be

```
Books.joins(:chapters)
  .group('books.id')
  .having('count() > 10')
```

UPDATE: I figured it out. Here what I did in rails if it helps anyone

```
query = <<-SQL
  UPDATE books AS b
  INNER JOIN
  (
      SELECT books.id
      FROM books
      JOIN chapters ON chapters.book_id = books.id
      GROUP BY books.id
      HAVING count(chapters.id) > 10
  ) i
  ON b.id = i.id
  SET long_book = true;
SQL

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me because I can't do anything with the data. It needs a select or where clause somewhere, because when I do this:

    Books.joins(:chapters)
      .group('books.id')
      .having('count() > 10')
      .update_all(long_book: true)

It updates ALL the books instead of the ones that are selected through the group by

Comment: Are you sure? `update_all` [purports to respect conditions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all).  Can you paste the generated SQL?

Comment: So after a bit of research, can't use group by in an update statement. 

This is what I get:

UPDATE `books` JOIN chapters ON chapters.book_id = books.id SET `long_book` = true

... notice that it leaves out the group by and having

Comment: Can you make it work in two passes? Force the group and having to evaluate then run the update? Essentially you want to receive all book ids then update all those books in a batch process.

Comment: So I got this far:

UPDATE books b
SET long_book = true
WHERE b.id IN (
  SELECT books.id
  FROM books
  JOIN chapters ON chapters.book_id = books.id
  GROUP BY books.id
  HAVING count(chapters.id) > 10
);

but I get this result:

ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'b' for update in FROM clause